# Docker Hub Login necessity for building a Docker Registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Should we log in to the docker hub to build our own private Docker Registry?

I have no idea about that, does anyone have any good documentation for building a docker registry? I am so confused.
what should I know for building a docker registry?( I am familier with docker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want a private *registry* or a private *repository*?  For a private registry you have to install a registry application like [Harbor](https://goharbor.io/) or [Docker Registry](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry) on your server (not Docker Hub), for a private repository you have to create an account on Docker Hub and then login.  A free account lets you create just one private repository (tipically used to push several versions or "tags" of one application) and many public repository, however paid accounts are also available.

Comment: I want a Docker Registry. By the way thanks a lot for your full explanation. @pino

Answer (score 0):

- Images are stored in collections, known as a repository
- A registry is a storage and content delivery system, holding named Docker images, available in different tagged versions. A registry instance may contain several repositories

E.g.: [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/) is a hosted Registry. Documentation concerning deploying a registry [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)